# os.path.isdir doesn't work If I call it from C++

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am trying ([copying](https://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/writing-a-python-plugin-api/)) a code for load python plugins into my C++ application.

This code works well itself. I've just add a function for call it from my c++ and a print for debugging:

```
import imp
import os

MainModule = "__init__"
PluginFolder = "plugins"

def getPlugins(ruta):   
    plugins = []
    possibleplugins = os.listdir(ruta + PluginFolder)
    for i in possibleplugins:
        location = os.path.join(PluginFolder, i)
        print (location)
        print (os.path.isdir(location))
        if not os.path.isdir(location) or not MainModule + ".py" in os.listdir(location):
            continue
        info = imp.find_module(MainModule, [location])      
        plugins.append({"name": i, "info": info})       
    return plugins


def loadPlugin(plugin):
    return imp.load_module(MainModule, *plugin["info"])


def iniciar(ruta):
    for i in getPlugins(ruta):
        print("Loading plugin " + i["name"])
        plugin = loadPlugin(i)
        plugin.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in getPlugins("/myabsolutepath/python/"):
        print("Loading plugin " + i["name"])
        plugin = loadPlugin(i)
        plugin.run()
```

I have a tree structure like:
`/myabsolutepath/python/plugins/`

And I have any dummy.py file and various folders for probe. Inside one of that folders I have a **init**.py file

If I run the script itself I have a right result:

```
plugins/dummy.py
False
plugins/C1
True
plugins/C3
True
plugins/C2
True
```

Now I try to call under my C++ function(Qt application):

```
void callplugins (const char* ruta, const char* nombremodulo, const char* nombrefuncion)
{
    qDebug()<<"ruta: "<<ruta;
    PyObject* modulo = nullptr;
    PyObject* pName = nullptr;
    PyObject* listado = nullptr;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path");
    PyObject *path = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)ruta);
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    if (result == 0 )
    {
        pName = PyUnicode_FromString(nombremodulo);
        modulo = PyImport_Import(pName);
        qDebug()<<"modulo "<<modulo;
        PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(1);
        PyObject* nombre = Py_BuildValue("s", ruta);
        PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, nombre);
        Py_DECREF(path);
        if (modulo)
        {
            pFuncion = PyObject_GetAttrString(modulo, nombrefuncion);
            Py_DECREF(modulo);
            if (pFuncion && PyCallable_Check(pFuncion))
            {
                qDebug()<<"Funcion exportar: "<<" -- "<<pFuncion;
                listado = PyObject_CallObject(pFuncion,args);
                Py_DECREF(args);
            }
        }
    }
    if (PyList_Check(listado))
    {
        qDebug()<<"okay "<<PyList_Size(listado);
        // okay, it's a list
        for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < PyList_Size(listado); ++i)
        {
            PyObject* siguiente = PyList_GetItem(listado, i);
            qDebug()<<"Siguiente: "<<siguiente;
            // do something with next
        }
    }
    qDebug()<<"Cargados los modulos";
}
```

And I get all false:

```
plugins/dummy.py
False
plugins/C1
False
plugins/C3
False
plugins/C2
False
```

Comment: 1. Have you printed the FULL file path in your python module to make sure there isn't an error converting the char* to PyObject then passing it to python?

2. Is there a reason why you're using os.path.isdir instead of os.path.exists? os.path.exists will return true if a file has the specified name where os.path.dir will not.

Comment: @λ John λ , very thank you for your answer. This was the problem. When I run the script in the console, in the top of the directory, it works because I am in the right path, but if I run the c++ code, the binary file is in other folder and it can't found nothing. I have fixed up it changing: location = os.path.join(PluginFolder, i) by location = os.path.join(ruta + PluginFolder, i)